# How to mock angular directive that has require field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, angular-directive

I've recently met with this problem:
I have: `directive-a`, `directive-b`

Directive-b has a `require: '^directive-a' fields which makes unit testing impossible.

I used to compile directive in this way in my unit tests:

```
element = $compile('<directive-a></directive-a>')($scope);
```

Then I can get the isolated scope with `element.isolateScope()`

But now because b has a dependency on a, i had to do like this:

```
element = $compile('<directive-a> <directive-b></directive-b> </directive-a>')($scope);
```

And in this case `element.isolateScope()` returns directive-a's scope instead of directive-b.

How can I get the scope of `directive-b`?

Demo:

Directive A:

```
(function(){
'use strict';

function directiveA(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/main/templates/directiveA.html',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            attr1: '='
        },
        controller: function($scope){
            //code...
        },
        link: function($scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude){
            injectContentIntoTemplate();

            function injectContentIntoTemplate(){
                transclude(function (clone) {
                    element.find('#specificElement').append(clone);
                });
            }
        }
    };
}

angular
    .module('myModule')
    .directive('directiveA', directiveA);
}());
```

Directive B:

```
(function(){
'use strict';

function directiveB(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/main/templates/directiveA.html',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            attr1: '@'
        },
        require: '^directiveA',
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            $scope.customVariable = 'something';
        }
    };
}

angular
    .module('myModule')
    .directive('directiveB', directiveB);
}());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Late answer, and untested.

```
let element = $compile('<directive-a> <directive-b></directive-b> </directive-a>')($scope);
let elementB = element.find('directive-b');
let BsScope = elementB.isolateScope();
```

Comment: Thanks @Huston but my question was how to mock and not how to compile. These are two different solutions. And I'd prefer mocking my inner directive rather than executing that too.

Comment: Hrm.  Your question is about accessing the inner directive's scope, and so that is what I tried to answer.  If you have another question about how to mock the inner directive, then you should ask that one as well. ;-)